# Javascript doesnt reload the page when tabbed out/ reloads only when on same tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I wrote a code using javascript/Youtube API + PHP which fetches YT video ID  from mysql server and places in javascript. I noticed that the reload occurs only when I am in current tab and not when i am tabbed out. It kind of messes up 
the whole idea of having an own website where i can put the library into MYSQL  and play it from there. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

```js
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player '."('
  player ', {
  height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: 'VyMznzLTIi8',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === 0) {
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's clearly not browsers fault. Browsers do reload pages when window is not focused. It's more like that this YT.Player doesn't fire a onPlayerStateChange event when window is not focused.
More than that, if you noticed, YT.Player will not even start a video if tab isn't focused.
I can't think of a way you can bypass that without patching YT library.

Comment: so are you saying that i need to use a custom opensource player to play the YT link? Can you recommend me one? I appreciate your answer though!